# user-kernel address division

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, paging, arm, mips

In ARM linux,  the  user-kernel  virtual address range is divided in the ratio 3:1.

But in MIPS linux,  this is usually 2:2

Does someone know what motivates this design difference ?

I have a faint idea that this has something to do with the fact that in MIPS, the TLB refill is managed in s/w and the kernel TLB entries are kind of hard-wired ensuring that they will never suffer a TLB miss.

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of the MIPS 32-bit architecture. User mode is limited to 2GB on most MIPS CPUs.

Only the lower 2GB virtual addresses (`0x0000_00000 to 0x7fff_ffff`) are accessible in user mode.  This part of the address space is called `kuseg`.  `Kuseg` addresses are translated by the TLB.  Whether TLB refills are done in software is irrelevant.

The kernel lives in the 512MB virtual space that extends from `0x8000_0000 to 9fff_ffff`.  This part of the address space is called `kseg0`.  Kseg0 addresses are not translated by the TLB.  These addresses are translated by removing the MSB (i.e. the virtual address range 0x8000_0000-9fff_ffff is hardwired to the physical address range `0x0000_0000-0x1fff_0000`)

Refer to a MIPS manual for more details.